# PayPal SOAP: "Declaration of PayPal::raiseError() should be compatible with that of PEAR::raiseError()"

Tags: php, paypal, pear

I have downloaded the [Paypal API for PHP (SOAP)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PHP_SOAP_SDK.tar.gz) and I'm getting this error:

> Strict standards: Declaration of
>   PayPal::raiseError() should be
>   compatible with that of
>   PEAR::raiseError() in
>   ....paypal/PayPal.php on line 24

when I call this:

```
$handler =& ProfileHandler_Array::getInstance(
        array(    'username'        => $this->api_username,
                'certificateFile' => $this->api_certificate,
                'signature'       => $this->api_signature,
                'subject'         => $this->api_subject,
                'environment'     => (($this->api_test)?'Sandbox':'Live')
        )
        );
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and should be fixed. Please open a report in the pear bugtracker.